# Superlight and powerful laptop for a programmer and a student

Tags: laptop, mobile-workstation

I'm a student and a programmer. I want to buy a laptop which I will use as a workstation. It should be very powerful as well as portable.

Budget: $1750

It should have:

- at least 16 GB of RAM (I will possibly play a little with virtual machines)
- Intel's HQ processor of the sixth generation would be the best. I don't want ultra-low voltage cpu.
- maximum 2,3 kg of weight
- 14 or 15 inch screen matte/antiglare screen with good resolution (HD+, FHD or better)
- not a MSI (I hate their keyboards), not a Macbook
- replaceable HDD (I already have mSATA SSD, I would like to install it using SATA adapter)
- not super expensive
- docking port would be a plus
- good battery

Does it exist?

---

There are some good laptops coming. I will probably go with Dell Precision 5000 (new version) or Dell XPS. I'm waiting for the end of this year to buy it. I'm not sure about the prices though. We'll see.

Comment: @AbcXyz, What do you mean by "does it exist"? **Most laptops allow you to add RAM and have replaceable HDD.** I'm using a [HP N1W13PA#AB4](https://www.google.com/search?q=HP+N1W13PA%23AB4) with Intel i7-5500U and 16 GB (half of it is addon) laptop right now and the total cost is under 1.3k SGD (= 915 USD). You can get the exact same thing at a much much cheaper price if you live in U.S.

Comment: I said I don't want an ultra-low voltage cpu.

Answer (score 4):

### [Origin EON-15X](https://www.originpc.com/) (Customizable)

### Score<sup>1</sup>: 81.8% (B-)

### For $1965 **(-)**

- 16GB RAM (2133MHz) **+**
- 1080p 15.6" Screen (Matte) **+**
- GTX 965M **+**
- i7 6700k (Desktop level processor @ 4Ghz (4.4Ghz turbo) **++**
- No HDD/SSD **+**
- 802.11ac WiFi **?**

### Score<sup>1</sup>: 91.6% (A-)

### For $2435 **(--)**

- 32GB RAM (2133Mhz) **++**
- i7 6700k (Desktop level processor @ 4Ghz (4.4Ghz turbo) **++**
- GTX 970M 6GB **+**
- 4K 2160p 15.6" Screen (Matte) **++**
- No HDD/SSD **+**
- 802.11ac **?**

### Chassis

- 1.4" thick
- a bit on the heavy side, 3.4kg **-**
- Two M.2 Drives, two 2.5" drives **+**
- Full size keyboard

### Battery

- According to Origin, 130 minutes, or 2h10m. **?**

<sup>1</sup> Score is calculated based on (number of pluses ÷ number of pluses & minuses combined)

[image]

Comment: I'm not going to try to compete with this beast.

Comment: @RookieTEC9 Haha :) I figured if he didn't want a low voltage CPU, this is what he needs. Of course, the battery life and size/weight aren't to good. Yours is leaning towards 'superlight', and mine is leaning more towards 'powerhouse'

Comment: What's wrong with low voltage CPU? You guys are confusing me.

Comment: @RookieTEC9 Your CPU isn't nearly as powerful as mine, and because it is low voltage, it isn't as powerful. I'm pretty sure the 6700k is over 3x as powerful than the 5600U, quite literally.

Comment: Oh, okay. `Voltage = Power`

Comment: @RookieTEC9 Yes. More power to the CPU = Higher Clock = More performance. Plus, my CPU has 4C/8T. Yours is 2C/4T. Double cores = double performance, not even including IPC and clock speeds. (Sorry, I'm a CPU geek. If there is one component you can ask me about, it's CPUs.

Comment: @RookieTEC9 Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31272/discussion-between-rubyjunk-and-rookietec9).

Comment: Unfortunately I can't buy this laptop where I live.

Comment: @AbcXyz Ouch. Where do you live? Can you add that to your post? Just the country, no one needs to know your address :)

Answer (score 1):

### [ThinkPad® W550 S](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/w-series/w550s/#tab-tech_specs) Notebook:

### Score<sup>1</sup>: 77.7% (C+)

1. 16 Gigs of Ram (+)
2. i7-5700U (--)
3. Weight of 2,2 kilograms [Non-touch screen] (+)
4. 15 inch with FHD or 3k (+)
5. Lenovo (+)
6. Removable storage (IDK) (?)
7. Price tag at $1,169 (+)
8. Website says 'docking connector' (+)
9. Battery life of 8 hours of video playback (+)
10. NVIDIA® K620M 2GB (?)

Summary:
It's an okay choice as we got a GPU, 16 (up to 32) gigs of ram, 3k display, but lets face it: this is a Lenovo. You will have to watch out for adware and bloatware.

<sup>1</sup> Score is calculated based on (number of pluses ÷ number of pluses & minuses combined)

Comment: Since OP is planning to replace the HD, bloatware probably won't be a problem. Just nuke the old one and flash windows on the the new one.

Comment: Unfortunately it has a ultra-low voltage CPU.

Comment: I have this machine via work. The only problem with this laptop (the bloatware is minimal) is that the keyboard is off-center due to the dedicated numpad and will take some getting used to. Also, the keyboard on this one doesn't have the same legendary feedback as the T-series or X-series, YMMV.